# Object not found within R function

Tags: r, environment, forecasting

I have a couple of `tslm` functions (from the `forecast` R package) inside a bigger function. I cannot seem to get them both to find their relevant objects. Including an explicit environment fixed one instance and broke the other. A minimal example follows:

```
library(forecast)
data(gas)

testlm <- function(x)
{
e<-new.env()
e$x<-x
   tslm(e$x~trend)->e$z
return(e$z)
}

testlm(gas)
```

This throws the following error:

```
 Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'e' not found
```

I also tried to explicitly give the formula the correct environment by setting

```
e$f<-as.formula("e$x~trend+season",env=e)
```

but got the exact same error.

P.S. The other error seems harder to reproduce, but getting this to work with the explicit environment should be enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out! To avoid messing with `tslm` or `lm`'s environments you can just put the data as a separate parameter. Changing the `tslm` line to

```
tslm(data ~ trend,data=e$x)
```

works normally.

Answer (score 0):

First, is there a reason you are doing like that instead of:

```
testlm <- function(x) {
   return(tslm(gas~trend))
}

 testlm(gas)
Call:
tslm(formula = gas ~ trend)

Coefficients:
(Intercept)        trend  
    -9029.6        127.7
```

I'm not sure why you need this new environment.

But, anyway. The issue is you're creating a new environment that is nested inside the environment of the function. When you use return, it is unable to pull out the value from this nested environment. Instead, you'd need to make this environment available globally by defining it prior to the function:

```
library(forecast)
data(gas)
e <- new.env()
testlm <- function(x) {
  e$x <- x
  e$z <- tslm(e$x~trend)
  return(e$z)
}

testlm(gas)
```

Comment: As I am trying to collect my functions in a package, I am somewhat reluctant to resort to setting environments outside them. Also, I tried setting `e` to have `emptyenv()' as a parent (while defined inside the function), but had the same error.